# How select a value from options list and display its fields in other place (e.g. in <input>)

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

I wanna select an object from select options and display its fields in some inputs.

So for example I select a bank account from list

```
<tr>
   <td>From account*</td>

   <td style="padding-right: 55px; width: 70%;">
      <select th:field="${transaction.accountNumberFrom}" required style="height: 30px;">
         <option  th:each="account : ${accounts}" th:text="${account.accountNumber} + ' &nbsp;&nbsp;(' + ${account.accountName} + ' : ' + ${account.bank} + ')'" th:value="${account.accountNumber}" />
      </select>
   </td>                                            
</tr>
```

and then want to automatically display it's field (e.g. ${account.currency}) in input field or sth.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try using javascript/jquery ?

Comment: I don't know javascript well but I tried to make a simple function called on onchange event 
   "function addCurrency(e) { document.getElementById("currency").value = e.target.value }"   
And... it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question doesn't provide details needed to answer, I am assuming few things and trying to answer.

You can use either pure `javascript` or `jquery` to achieve this. Here is one example using `jquery`

I assume you have your input field something like

```
<input type="text" name="myinput" id="myinput">
```

Now you use `jquery on` as below

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  $('#myinput').val(this.value);
});
```

Comment: To put field other than _value_ in my _input_ I had to modify it a little
`function addC() {            
                $('input.currency').val($('select.select option:selected').prop('title'));
        }`

It didn't fired at first time so I had to start it by other method
`function addCurrency() {
            $('select.select').on('change', addC());
        }`

And... it works :) Thanks man!